# Query through SPListCollection

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I wonder if it's somehow possible to query a `SPListCollection` object using `SPQuery`, as with `SPListItemCollection`. Imagine that you want to find out which lists were created by a given `Author` or visible for a given user, for example.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with SPQuery! But i would prefer you using KeywordQuery:

```
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://server/sitecollection"))
        {
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(siteCollection);
            keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";

            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
            ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);

            var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();

            DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table;
        }
```

Within the Keywordquery you could use for example contentclass STSList to retrieve only lists. And in this case when only using contentclass:"STSList" then you would get all lists where the executor has permissions. You can narrow down by adding additional query parameters. SharePoint search is what you are looking for.